# Calculate the median based on multiple grouping columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

How to calculate the median time when grouped by multiple columns?

| order_start | order_ready | COMPANY | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 18:55:00 | 2018-01-01 19:05:00 | x | 223 |
| 2018-01-01 18:55:00 | 2018-01-01 19:05:00 | x | 224 |
| 2018-01-01 18:55:00 | 2018-01-01 19:05:00 | y | 225 |
| 2018-01-01 18:55:00 | 2018-01-01 19:05:00 | y | 226 |

What I can do using

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) as count,
    COMPANY as company ,
    YEAR(order_start) as year,
    MONTH(order_start) as month
FROM table
GROUP BY
    YEAR(order_start),
    MONTH(order_start),
    COMPANY;
```

| count | company | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | x | 2018 | 1 |
| 2 | y | 2018 | 1 |

What I want is also the median order time calculated on the orders within each company, year, and month

| count | company | year | month | median_order_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | x | 2018 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | y | 2018 | 1 | 10 |

I can calculate the waiting time for each trip using the below query, but how do I calculate the median to produce the last table? I am using SQL Server 2017

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, order_start, order_ready))
```

Comment: See also https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/grouped-median